# Set value of SMT leaf proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I would like to make a zk proof that would set the leaf of an SMT tree at an index that is an eth address to 1. The SMT is built offchain.

I already have the SMT and the root of the tree onchain.

I only want the *from* root and the *to* root to be public.

Any suggestions on how to implement this using circom?

Also looking for similar proofs that update data in trees if anyone can suggest some.